# Is there a generalization of Leibniz integral rule to contour integrals?

Tags: contour-integration, leibniz-integral-rule

I am interested in applying Leibniz integral rule to the following general contour integral.

$$ g(r)=\int_{f(x,y)=r} h(x,y) d\Gamma(x,y) $$
Note that the dependence on r exists only through the contour $f(x,y)=r$, and that $h(x,y)$ is independent of r.

Thus, I need some expression for $$ \frac{d }{dr}g(r) = ??? $$
It seems it might be something like
$$ \frac{d }{dr}g(r) = [ h(x,y) ]_{\partial(f(x,y)-r)} $$ but I'm not confident and unable to find any resources for this subject. Also, $\partial(f(x,y)-r)$ refers to the boundary of the curve $(f(x,y)=r)$ which may be a null set.

Thank you for your attention.